# Stop processing if application window is totally obscured

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am developing a WPF application when the application is shown a thread work 
and show a refreshed data on the application ui .

for saving performances i want to stop this Thread if the application is 100% covered by another application .

for example if the user is using another application that take the right half of the screen ,and my app is shown on the left half of the screen , the app must steel works cause the user is using the other app and watching the 
changed data on my app .
if the application is back grounded or 100% covered by another app window or 
minimized must stops;

i tried many solution like using the Deactivation event of the window
and p invoke but that not resolve the situation.

and thanks you.

Comment: I don't remember exactly how something like this is wrapped in WPF, but if it were a straight API app, I might experiment with invalidating my client rectangle every once in a while on a timer. That will trigger Windows into posting a WM_PAINT message to the window but only if the window is visible.